# Building Apache Roller on Windows 7

Tags: java, maven, ant, apache-roller

I am getting this kind of error when i tried to build apache roller on my windows 7 service pack 1 64 bit.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (gen-db-scripts) on project roller-webapp: An Ant BuildException has occured: Exception thrown by 'generator.parse'. For more information consult the velocity log, or invoke ant with the -debug flag.
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<texen outputFile="README.txt" controlTemplate="control.vm" outputDirectory="F:\roller-trunk\app/target/dbscripts" templatePath="F:\roller-trunk\app/src/main/resources/sql" contextProperties="F:\roller-trunk\app/src/main/resources/sql/dbscripts.properties"/>... @ 5:261 in F:\roller-trunk\app\target\antrun\build-main.xml: F:\roller-trunk\app\target\dbscripts\db2\createdb.sql (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (gen-db-scripts) on project roller-webapp: An Ant BuildException has occured: Exception thrown by 'generator.parse'. For more information consult the velocity log, or invoke ant with the -debug flag.
around Ant part ...<texen outputFile="README.txt" controlTemplate="control.vm" outputDirectory="F:\roller-trunk\app/target/dbscripts" templatePath="F:\roller-trunk\app/src/main/resources/sql" contextProperties="F:\roller-trunk\app/src/main/resources/sql/dbscripts.properties"/>... @ 5:261 in F:\roller-trunk\app\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

i suspect this **outputDirectory="F:\roller-trunk\app/target/dbscripts" templatePath="F:\roller-trunk\app/src/main/resources/sql"**` is the problem but i have no idea how to fix it. I ran the "mvn clean install" from my command prompt.

Comment: Could you try executing `mvn -X generate-resources`? is any output there in velocity.log?

Comment: no output in velocity.log, it's completely empty

Comment: Hmm OK... I'd investigate it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded building Roller source code in current SVN trunk (5.2.0-SNAPSHOT) on Windows 7 box without errors. output of `mvn -version` is following:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T20:57:37+09:00)
Maven home: c:\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
Default locale: ja_JP, platform encoding: MS932
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

Could you try building with same version of JDK/Maven to the above output?

**UPDATE**

Now GitHub distribution of Roller can be built without this error. For detail check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ROL-2086

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't store the empty directories that Roller needs to do the build, if this patch were applied (https://github.com/apache/roller/pull/3) the problem would be fixed.

My work-in-progress Github fork of Roller, TightBlog, already has this change in place: https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog.  But TightBlog is not ready for regular use.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this error happens because of direct pull from the Github version. At first, I've tried to pull it from Github and I faced the same problem. Later on, I've tried to checkout it directly from the SVN trunk and there's no problem with the building process.

I believe this error has also been described previously at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.roller.devel/5895. It is stated that there might be some problems with the Github version.